# How to read the gem file specifications from extconf.rb?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm building a Ruby gem file that has various 3rd party executable requirements (some non-ruby tools that the gem will then use through system calls).

The requirement list is specified using the gemspec informative `requirements` list, and I was tasked with creating a set up where that requirement list is verified during installation - essentially converting the `requirements` list from being informative to being authoritative.

My initial approach is to use `extensions`, like in the `extconf.rb` pattern, to run some ruby code during installation that will verify the list of requirements and fail the installation if the requirements are not met.

So my current implementation is using a `ext/Rakefile`, that reads gemspec file using a hard-coded path, parses the `requirements` list using a custom (but straight-forward and simple) syntax and run some simple tests on the required executables.

I would really want to factor out the dependency on knowing the path to the gemspec file, so I can reuse the code in a modular way on other projects.

For completion (and in the hopes that it will be useful for someone), here's my code - which uses the `Gem::Ext::Builder` "Rakefile mode" to just run some arbitrary code.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mkmf'

def verify_requirement(reqspec)
  exe, version_spec, version_regex = reqspec.split(/\s*,\s*/,3)

  exe = $1 if exe =~ /\[([^\]]+)\]/ # support human readable alias for executable name

  abort "Missing required executable #{exe}!" unless find_executable(exe)
  return unless version_spec # no version is specified, so executable existing is good enough

  version = %x|#{exe} --version 2>&1|.chomp
  version = %x|#{exe} -version 2>&1|.chomp unless $?.success? 
  abort "Error checking for version of #{exe}: (#{$?.exitstatus}) #{version}" unless $?.success?

  if version_regex
    abort "Version test '#{version_regex}' failed to match '#{version}'!" unless version =~ /#{version_regex}/m
    abort "Version test '#{version_regex}' failed to generate a version number!" unless $1
    version = $1
  end

  abort "Failed to locate a valid version number for #{exe}, found '#{version}'" unless version =~ /^[0-9\.]+/
  abort "Insufficient version '#{version}' for #{exe} - requires #{version_spec}"  unless Gem::Dependency.new(exe, version_spec).match? exe, version
end

task :default do
  gemspec = File.absolute_path('../my.gemspec')
  Gem::Specification::load(gemspec).requirements.each do |req|
    verify_requirement(req)
  end
end
```

This code requires that the `requirements` uses either of these syntaxes:

- `exe-file[, <semantic-version-spec>[, <version-garabbing-regex>]]`
- `alias '[' exe-file ']'[, <semantic-version-spec>[, <version-garabbing-regex>]]`

For example:

```
spec.requirements << 'sox'
spec.requirements << 'ffmpeg, >= 2.5, ffmpeg version ([\d\.]+)'
spec.requirements << 'ImageMagick [convert], >= 6.7.5, ImageMagick ([\d\.]+)'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Gem::Specification` class can be used to load and parse the `gemspec`. I'm using the following code in `ext/Rakefile` to perform tasks based on the `gemspec` file:

```
task :default do
  gemspec = File.absolute_path('../gemname.gemspec')
  Gem::Specification::load(gemspec).requirements.each do |req|
    verify_requirement(req)
  end
end
```